# Appium IOS loading all page elements

Tags: performance, load, appium, appium-ios

Some test scenarios I run load elements such as tables and lists, according to the development team the loading behavior should be identical to that implemented in Android, making requests to populate the screen as the user scrolled down. But on screens only 5 elements should appear and the appium inspector detects all the elements.

Is there any capability we can pass so that it doesn't load that much data?

Ao carregar estes elementos todos o appium não consegue interagir com nenhum elemento na pagina, impedindo os fluxos de automação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.

This is how the mobile "DOM" (It's not precise to say DOM for mobile I believe, but works for the example) works in iOS, it loads the **entire** thing on the DOM, even the elements that are not visible, in other hand, Android only load on the DOM what you can see.

So you need to manage this difference on your testing framework.